# Photoshop text layer has jagged edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, pixelation, visual-artifacts

I have created a text layer in Photoshop. The corners of the text have jagged edges, how can I display my text without the jagged edges?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the example you linked to, it looks like the zoom level in Photoshop is set to more than 100%, which will make the pixels visible.  Set your zoom to 100% instead.  Don't zoom in on raster images if you don't want to see the pixels. If you want to increase the size of the font, choose a larger font size.

Example showing text at 100%, and pixelization when zoomed in.

[image: Example text show pixelization when zoomed in]

If the above isn't your problem, then another thing to check is the anti-aliasing option in the tool options for the text tool. Make sure it is set to something other than "none". Try the different settings.

Location of the anti-aliasing options:

[image: Photoshop anti-aliasing options]

Answer (score 3):

Open Character panel and check Sharpness options:

[image: net]

Comment: @RamaKrishnan if this is what solved your problem than this should be the accepted answer, not the other.